# Non-Static Variable Cannot be Referenced From a Static Context: New to GUIs

Tags: java, user-interface, variables, static, jtextfield

Whenever I compile this, I get an error reading "non-static variable french cannot be referenced from a static context". I have just started working with GUIs, but I cannot find an answer to this. I'm sure it's something simple, but I cannot figure it out!

Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

```
 public class ReportCard {
 JTextField french = new JTextField ("French Grade") ;
 public static void main (String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Report Card") ;
    frame.setSize(400 , 600) ;
    frame.setVisible(true) ;
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;

    JPanel bigPanel = new JPanel() ;
    frame.getContentPane().add(bigPanel) ;

    bigPanel.add(french) ;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly suggest reading up on how static works there are many people who can explain it much better than i can.For now you can do a couple of things. 
make french static

```
 static JTextField french = new JTextField ("French Grade") ;
```

or  put it in to the main method which will inherently make it static since its already in a static context.

```
public class ReportCard {
 public static void main (String args[]) {
    JTextField french = new JTextField ("French Grade") ;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Report Card") ;
    frame.setSize(400 , 600) ;
    frame.setVisible(true) ;
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;

    JPanel bigPanel = new JPanel() ;
    frame.getContentPane().add(bigPanel) ;

    bigPanel.add(french) ;
```

Comment: `static`, or "global" variables are a bad idea in normal programming, they are a complete pain in the API within a GUI environment, it's to easy for the reference of the variable to be changed unexpectedly and the whole program to crumble apart.  A better solution would be to use the `ReportCard` class's constructor or other methods to build the UI and use the `main` method to get it started...

Answer (score 1):

The variable, `french` is an instance field of `ReportCard`, it has no context or meaning outside of an instance of `ReportCard`, this means that unless you first create an instance of `ReportCard`, you can't reference the variable.

While you could make `french` `static`, this leads you down a dark path of potential issues and is generally a bad idea, it's to easy for the `static` reference to be changed and your whole program to come apart.  `static` is also NOT a cross object communication mechanism and should never be used as as such.

Instead, you could use `ReportCard` to create your UI, for example...

```
public class ReportCard {
 JTextField french = new JTextField ("French Grade") ;
 public static void main (String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ReportCard reportCard = new ReportCard();
            reportCard.start();
        }
    }
 }

 public void start() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Report Card") ;
    frame.setSize(400 , 600) ;
    frame.setVisible(true) ;
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;

    JPanel bigPanel = new JPanel() ;
    frame.getContentPane().add(bigPanel) ;

    bigPanel.add(french) ;   
 }
```